# How to get specific string out of long string

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have the following String (it is variable, but classpath is always the same):

```
C:.Users.mho.Desktop.Eclipse.workspace.GIT.BLUBB...bin.de.test.class.mho.communication.InterfaceXmlHandler
```

and I want to get just

```
de.test.class.mho.communication.InterfaceXmlHandler
```

out of this string. The end

```
InterfaceXmlHandler
```

is variable, also the beginning before 'de' and the path itself is variable too, but

```
de.test.class.mho.
```

isn't variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use

```
String result = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("de.test.class.mho."));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting you could get rid of the beginning of the string:

```
String input = "C:.Users.mho.Desktop.Eclipse.workspace.GIT.BLUBB...bin.de.test.class.mho.communication.InterfaceXmlHandler";
String output = input.replaceAll(".*(de\\.test\\.class\\.mho.*)", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string-array with [String.split("de.test.class.mho.")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). The Array will contain two Strings, the second String will be what you want.

```
String longString = ""; //whatever
String[] urlArr = longString.split("de.test.class.mho.");
String result;

if(urlArr.length > 1) {
  result = "de.test.class.mho." urlArr[1]; //de.test.class.mho.whatever.whatever.whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceAll()` to "extract" the part you want:

```
String part = str.replaceAll(".*(?=de\\.test\\.class\\.mho\\.)", "");
```

This uses a look-ahead to find all characters *before* the target, and replace them with a blank (ie delete them).

---

You could quite reasonably ignore escaping the dots for brevity:

```
String part = str.replaceAll(".*(?=de.test.class.mho.)", "");
```

I doubt it would give a different result.